# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to4}(x-4)\cdot\cot(x-4)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

It's been a while since I've done calc, so I'm trying to review by reading "Calculus Demystified" by Steven G. Krantz. Question 1c at the end of chapter 2 has me stumped:

$$\lim_{x\to4}(x-4)\cdot\cot(x-4)$$

The graph of this indicates that the limit approaches 0, but the answer in the back of the book has this:

$$\lim_{x\to4}(x-4)\cdot\cot(x-4) = \lim_{x\to4}[(x-4)/\sin(x-4)]\cdot\cos(x-4) = 1\cdot1 = 1$$

I understand that $\cot(x-4) = \cos(x-4)/\sin(x-4)$, but why is the answer so different from the graph? Could it be an error in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph agrees with the limit. [Look at $a$ near $0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+a*cot+a) (substituting $a$ for $x-4$).

By the way, the solution you reproduced uses [this fairly well-known limit](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X). It is useful to know this (and why it's true) since it can often be applied to other limits.

Comment: I must have done something terribly wrong in graphing it then. My TI-86 doesn't have `cot` so I used `tan^-1`. Is that right?

Comment: @DaveKennedy Oh, I think that is more the notation's fault than your fault. The  $^{-1}$ refers to the inverse (not the reciprocal) of the tangent function. So what you graphed was an expression using arctangent instead of cotangent :)

Comment: Ah, so to graph `cot` I probably need to enter `1/tan`?

Comment: @DaveKennedy If you try it again and explicitly write out "(x-4)/tan(x-4)" it should work. EDIT: yes, you're right